# Bypass setter for property in swift

Tags: swift

I want to set a property in  my own class which has got a setter without that setter being called. Is that possible?

```
override var textColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        super.textColor = newValue
        // some additional code here
    }
    get {
        return super.textColor
    }
}
```

I tried to set like this `_textColor = UIColor.blackColor()` but that doesn't work. I want "some additional code" to only run when `textColor` is set from outside and not from within my own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need dual access control, you can create a private stored property, and expose it outside via a computed property. However in your case the stored property is already implemented in the superclass, so that solution "as is" won't work.

The only way to achieve what you need is to create 2 computed properties, one for external usage, the other one for internal:

```
private var _textColor: UIColor? {
    get { return super.textColor }
    set { super.textColor = newValue }
}

override var textColor: UIColor? {
    get { return super.textColor }
    set {
        super.textColor = newValue
        // Additional processing here
    }
```

But in this case you have to remember to use the private one from within the class code

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You’ll have to define an additional variable and keep it private. E.g.

```
private var _textColor: UIColor?
override var textColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        _textColor = newValue
        super.textColor = newValue
        // some additional code here
    }
    get {
        return _textColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite fit my needs, but I found another solution. I guess the answer is that no - you cannot bypass it. Your solution will work for most I guess.

Comment: @Johannes If you found a solution and it works for you, please post it as an answer!

Comment: @Antonio has a better solution that he just posted, I'll accept that when the time-limit has passed for when you can accept an answer after asking it